# google charts graphs set legend value and same color columns

Tags: jquery, charts, google-visualization

data = [["product1",3.6126719999999977],["product2",6.827597999999999],["product2",1008.0]] when i use array data and implement in columns or bar charts that time is displayed legend as value only not 'diffrent product name' and all bar charts look same color columns. i want to add legend name as product name and diffrent color to all columns

```js
    google.charts.load('current', {
      packages: ['corechart']
    }).then(function () {
     

      
     $.ajax({
        url: 'path to data',
        dataType: 'json'
      }).done(function (jsonData) {
        loadData(jsonData);
      }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        var jsonData = [["product1",450],["product2",23],["product3",1008.0]];
        loadData(jsonData, '1', 'Column');
      });

      // load json data
      function loadData(jsonData, id, chartType) {
        // create data table
        var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

        switch (chartType) {
          case 'Column':
            // add date column
            dataTable.addColumn('string', 'Product');
            dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Value');

            $.each(jsonData, function(productIndex, product) {
              // add product data
              dataTable.addRow([
                product[0],
                product[1],
              ]);
            });
            break;

         
        }

        // draw chart
        $(window).resize(function () {
          drawChart(id, chartType, dataTable);
        });
        drawChart(id, chartType, dataTable);
      }

      // save charts for redraw
      var charts = {};
      var options = {
        Column: {
          chartArea: {
            height: '100%',
            width: '100%',
            top: 64,
            left: 64,
            right: 32,
            bottom: 48
          },
          height: '100%',
          legend: {
            position: 'top'
          },
          pointSize: 4,
          width: '100%'
        },
        Pie: {
          height: '100%',
          width: '100%'
        },
        Line: {
          height: '100%',
          width: '100%',
          legend: {
            position: 'bottom'
          },
          pointSize: 4,
          width: '100%'
        }

      };

      // draw chart
       function drawChart(id, chartType, dataTable) {
        if (!charts.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
          charts[id] = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
            chartType: chartType + 'Chart',
            containerId: 'chart-' + id,
            options: options[chartType]
          });
        }
        charts[id].setDataTable(dataTable);
        charts[id].draw();
      }
    });
```

```css
    html, body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    }

    .chart {
      display: inline-block;
      height: 100%;
      width: 32%;
    }
```

```html
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <div class="chart" id="chart-0"></div>
    <div class="chart" id="chart-1"></div>
    <div class="chart" id="chart-2"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in this case, you want to create **columns** for each product,
instead of **rows** for each product...

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  // save charts for redraw
  var charts = {};
  var options = {
    Column: {
      chartArea: {
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        top: 64,
        left: 64,
        right: 32,
        bottom: 48
      },
      height: '100%',
      legend: {
        position: 'top'
      },
      pointSize: 4,
      width: '100%'
    },
    Pie: {
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%'
    },
    Line: {
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%',
      legend: {
        position: 'bottom'
      },
      pointSize: 4,
      width: '100%'
    }
  };

  var jsonData = [["product1",450],["product2",23],["product3",1008.0]];
  loadData(jsonData, '1', 'Column');

  // load json data
  function loadData(jsonData, id, chartType) {
    // create data table
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    switch (chartType) {
      case 'Column':
        // add date column
        dataTable.addColumn('string', 'Category');
        var rowIndex = dataTable.addRow();
        dataTable.setValue(rowIndex, 0, dataTable.getColumnLabel(0));

        $.each(jsonData, function(productIndex, product) {
          var colIndex = dataTable.addColumn('number', product[0]);
          // add product data
          dataTable.setValue(rowIndex, colIndex, product[1]);
        });
        break;
    }

    // draw chart
    $(window).resize(function () {
      drawChart(id, chartType, dataTable);
    });
    drawChart(id, chartType, dataTable);
  }

  // draw chart
  function drawChart(id, chartType, dataTable) {
    if (!charts.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
      charts[id] = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        chartType: chartType + 'Chart',
        containerId: 'chart-' + id,
        options: options[chartType]
      });
    }
    charts[id].setDataTable(dataTable);
    charts[id].draw();
  }
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.chart {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div class="chart" id="chart-1"></div>
```

Comment: thank you so much i have one que about how to add more one variable pass to load function? var jsonData = [["product1",450],["product2",23],["product3",1008.0]];
  loadData(jsonData, '1', 'Column');   same i make like .. var jsonData2 = [["product1",450],["product2",23],["product3",1008.0]];
  loadData(jsonData2, '1', 'Column');   pass to function loadData(jsonData, jsonData2 id, chartType) but i got error . i dont want to use every time ajax call just only use varible value and load in loaddata funtion .i have 7 graphs in one page so its take time to load in fornt side how can i do it ?

Comment: sorry, don't really understand, why do you need to send multiple json data? why not just call load data multiple times? doesn't have to be with ajax, as in answer above...

Comment: means i don't want to use ajax call just only make variable data pass to like this way possible ? var1= new.to_json ; var2= new2.to_json;      function loadData(var1,var2, id, chartType)

Comment: you'll want to load twice -- `loadData(var1, id, chartType); loadData(var2, id, chartType);` -- can't load two charts with same id...

Comment: small silly question?  can I use ControlWrapper as a product name in this charts string as a category work?

Comment: don't really understand the question but you can use a CategoryFilter ControlWrapper on any string column -- [here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37725501/5090771)

Comment: yes, same as a filter with a product name or category name ...instead of date wise ...

Comment: thanks for sharing a link but can you check this code for range filter wt pro? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50221655/string-filter-and-control-filter-data-google-charts

Comment: hi how can i add cost text or label on every top of columns like 450$ on top of product 1 ?  how can i add role :annotation in this graph ?

Comment: like this way but outside columns example : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43534064/how-to-put-labels-over-the-bars-google-charts-bar..

Comment: use option for `annotations.alwaysOutside`

Comment: hi can you help me for annotation implement with your code ? i am confusing with  how to add raw and column here my quetion thank you in advance...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50789740/how-to-make-annotation-role-true-dynamic-in-google-charts-using-data-table-and

Comment: hi can you check my new question about annotations issue? i tried with your diff method but still i am stuck in labels ...here que and working charts https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50789740/how-to-make-annotation-role-true-dynamic-in-google-charts-using-data-table-and    thanks in advance