# string filter and control filter data more than one google charts

Tags: jquery, charts, google-visualization

i am stuck in range filter for google charts for stack columns graph just i want to display data with some range..can you find what is a problem with category filter?
how can i display filter by date range? 
is there any other option to filter by product name also? 
thank you so much in advance ................

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart','controls']
}).then(function () {
  // save charts for redraw
  var charts = {};
  var options = {
    isStacked :'true',
    Column: {
      chartArea: {
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        top: 60,
        left: 64,
        right: 32,
        bottom: 48,
      },
      hAxis: {
        format: 'ddd'
      },
      height: '100%',
      legend: {
        position: 'top'
      },
      width: '100%'
    },
    Pie: {
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%'
    }
  };
  var formatDate = new google.visualization.DateFormat({
    pattern: 'MMM yyyy'
  });

  var controlCat = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
    containerId: 'category_div',
    options: {
      filterColumnIndex: 0
    }
  });

  var controlStr = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'StringFilter',
    containerId: 'string_div',
    options: {
      matchType: 'any',
      filterColumnIndex: 0
    }
  });
  

  // get data
  var jsonData = [{"name":"p1","data":[["2017/01/01",1.539011],["2017/01/02",4.22612],["2017/01/03",9.685247],["2017/01/04",8.535989],["2017/01/14",18.260888],["2017/01/15",57.279945],["2017/01/16",61.24776],["2017/01/17",65.12251399999998],["2017/01/18",69.15200200000001],["2017/01/19",73.13965199999997],["2017/01/20",77.10624],["2017/01/21",81.127521],["2017/01/22",85.04579900000002],["2017/01/23",89.003693],["2017/01/24",92.817327],["2017/01/25",64.12351600000001],["2017/02/04",4.734462000000001],["2017/02/05",17.073667999999998],["2017/02/06",21.047981999999998],["2017/02/07",16.340846]]},{"name":"p2","data":[["2017/01/01",3.4],["2017/01/02",8.8],["2017/01/03",19.4],["2017/01/04",16.9],["2017/01/14",33.8],["2017/01/15",106.19999999999999],["2017/01/16",113.4],["2017/01/17",120.6],["2017/01/18",127.79999999999998],["2017/01/19",135.0],["2017/01/20",142.20000000000002],["2017/01/21",149.5],["2017/01/22",156.6],["2017/01/23",163.79999999999998],["2017/01/24",170.70000000000002],["2017/01/25",118.0],["2017/02/04",9.3],["2017/02/05",32.7],["2017/02/06",39.900000000000006],["2017/02/07",30.6],["2017/04/14",16.6]]},{"name":"p3","data":[["2017/01/01",0.090284],["2017/01/02",0.18148],["2017/01/03",0.36250400000000005],["2017/01/04",0.3223319999999999],["2017/01/14",0.629936],["2017/01/15",1.9858830000000007],["2017/01/16",2.117427],["2017/01/17",2.248054],["2017/01/18",2.3795070000000007],["2017/01/19",2.510548],["2017/01/20",2.6411759999999997],["2017/01/21",2.806806],["2017/01/22",2.9025950000000007],["2017/01/23",3.0344140000000004],["2017/01/24",3.156505],["2017/01/25",2.18585],["2017/02/04",0.200327],["2017/02/05",0.700937],["2017/02/06",0.8522410000000002],["2017/02/07",0.651459]]}];
  loadData(jsonData, '0', 'Column');
  
  var jsonData2 = [{"name":"p1","data":[["2017/01/01",1.539011],["2017/01/02",4.22612],["2017/01/03",9.685247],["2017/01/04",8.535989],["2017/01/14",18.260888],["2017/01/15",57.279945],["2017/01/16",61.24776],["2017/01/17",65.12251399999998],["2017/01/18",69.15200200000001],["2017/01/19",73.13965199999997],["2017/01/20",77.10624],["2017/01/21",81.127521],["2017/01/22",85.04579900000002],["2017/01/23",89.003693],["2017/01/24",92.817327],["2017/01/25",64.12351600000001],["2017/02/04",4.734462000000001],["2017/02/05",17.073667999999998],["2017/02/06",21.047981999999998],["2017/02/07",16.340846]]},{"name":"p2","data":[["2017/01/01",3.4],["2017/01/02",8.8],["2017/01/03",19.4],["2017/01/04",16.9],["2017/01/14",33.8],["2017/01/15",106.19999999999999],["2017/01/16",113.4],["2017/01/17",120.6],["2017/01/18",127.79999999999998],["2017/01/19",135.0],["2017/01/20",142.20000000000002],["2017/01/21",149.5],["2017/01/22",156.6],["2017/01/23",163.79999999999998],["2017/01/24",170.70000000000002],["2017/01/25",118.0],["2017/02/04",9.3],["2017/02/05",32.7],["2017/02/06",39.900000000000006],["2017/02/07",30.6],["2017/04/14",16.6]]},{"name":"p3","data":[["2017/01/01",0.090284],["2017/01/02",0.18148],["2017/01/03",0.36250400000000005],["2017/01/04",0.3223319999999999],["2017/01/14",0.629936],["2017/01/15",1.9858830000000007],["2017/01/16",2.117427],["2017/01/17",2.248054],["2017/01/18",2.3795070000000007],["2017/01/19",2.510548],["2017/01/20",2.6411759999999997],["2017/01/21",2.806806],["2017/01/22",2.9025950000000007],["2017/01/23",3.0344140000000004],["2017/01/24",3.156505],["2017/01/25",2.18585],["2017/02/04",0.200327],["2017/02/05",0.700937],["2017/02/06",0.8522410000000002],["2017/02/07",0.651459]]}];
  loadData(jsonData2, '1', 'Column');
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  

  // load json data
  function loadData(jsonData, id, chartType) {
    // create data table
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    switch (chartType) {
      case 'Column':
        // add date column
        dataTable.addColumn('date', 'Date');
        var aggColumns = [];
        var viewColumns = [0, {
          calc: function (dt, row) {
            return formatDate.formatValue(dt.getValue(row, 0));
          },
          label: dataTable.getColumnLabel(0),
          type: 'string'
        }];

        $.each(jsonData, function(productIndex, product) {
          // add product column
          var colIndex = dataTable.addColumn('number', product.name);
          viewColumns.push(colIndex);
          aggColumns.push({
            aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum,
            column: colIndex+1,
            label: dataTable.getColumnLabel(colIndex),
            type: dataTable.getColumnType(colIndex)
          });

          // add product data
          $.each(product.data, function(dataIndex, data) {
            var rowIndex = dataTable.addRow();
            var rowDate = new Date(data[0]);
            dataTable.setValue(rowIndex, 0, new Date(rowDate.getFullYear(), rowDate.getMonth(), 1));
            dataTable.setValue(rowIndex, colIndex, data[1]);
          });
        });

        var dataView = new google.visualization.DataView(dataTable);
        dataView.setColumns(viewColumns);
        var groupData = google.visualization.data.group(
          dataView,
          [0, 1],
          aggColumns
        );
        var dataView = new google.visualization.DataView(groupData);
        dataView.hideColumns([0]);
        dataTable = dataView;
        break;
    }

    // draw chart
    $(window).resize(function () {
      drawChart(id, chartType, dataTable);
    });
    drawChart(id, chartType, dataTable);
  }

  // draw chart
  function drawChart(id, chartType, dataTable) {
    if (!charts.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
      charts[id] = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        chartType: 'ColumnChart',
        containerId: 'chart-' + id,
        options: {
          isStacked: true
        }
      });
    }
    var dash = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard'));
    dash.bind([controlCat, controlStr], charts[id]);
    dash.draw(dataTable);
  }

});
```

```css
.control {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="dashboard">
<div class="control" id="string_div"></div>
  <div class="control" id="category_div"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart-0"></div>
</div>
<div id="dashboard">
<div class="control" id="string_div"></div>
  <div class="control" id="category_div"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart-1"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the controls were out of scope, couldn't be reached by `drawChart`

just needed to move them out of `loadData`,

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart','controls']
}).then(function () {
  // save charts for redraw
  var charts = {};
  var options = {
    isStacked :'true',
    Column: {
      chartArea: {
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        top: 60,
        left: 64,
        right: 32,
        bottom: 48,
      },
      hAxis: {
        format: 'ddd'
      },
      height: '100%',
      legend: {
        position: 'top'
      },
      width: '100%'
    },
    Pie: {
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%'
    }
  };
  var formatDate = new google.visualization.DateFormat({
    pattern: 'MMM yyyy'
  });

  var controlCat = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
    containerId: 'category_div',
    options: {
      filterColumnIndex: 0
    }
  });

  var controlStr = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'StringFilter',
    containerId: 'string_div',
    options: {
      matchType: 'any',
      filterColumnIndex: 0
    }
  });

  // get data
  var jsonData = [{"name":"p1","data":[["2017/01/01",1.539011],["2017/01/02",4.22612],["2017/01/03",9.685247],["2017/01/04",8.535989],["2017/01/14",18.260888],["2017/01/15",57.279945],["2017/01/16",61.24776],["2017/01/17",65.12251399999998],["2017/01/18",69.15200200000001],["2017/01/19",73.13965199999997],["2017/01/20",77.10624],["2017/01/21",81.127521],["2017/01/22",85.04579900000002],["2017/01/23",89.003693],["2017/01/24",92.817327],["2017/01/25",64.12351600000001],["2017/02/04",4.734462000000001],["2017/02/05",17.073667999999998],["2017/02/06",21.047981999999998],["2017/02/07",16.340846]]},{"name":"p2","data":[["2017/01/01",3.4],["2017/01/02",8.8],["2017/01/03",19.4],["2017/01/04",16.9],["2017/01/14",33.8],["2017/01/15",106.19999999999999],["2017/01/16",113.4],["2017/01/17",120.6],["2017/01/18",127.79999999999998],["2017/01/19",135.0],["2017/01/20",142.20000000000002],["2017/01/21",149.5],["2017/01/22",156.6],["2017/01/23",163.79999999999998],["2017/01/24",170.70000000000002],["2017/01/25",118.0],["2017/02/04",9.3],["2017/02/05",32.7],["2017/02/06",39.900000000000006],["2017/02/07",30.6],["2017/04/14",16.6]]},{"name":"p3","data":[["2017/01/01",0.090284],["2017/01/02",0.18148],["2017/01/03",0.36250400000000005],["2017/01/04",0.3223319999999999],["2017/01/14",0.629936],["2017/01/15",1.9858830000000007],["2017/01/16",2.117427],["2017/01/17",2.248054],["2017/01/18",2.3795070000000007],["2017/01/19",2.510548],["2017/01/20",2.6411759999999997],["2017/01/21",2.806806],["2017/01/22",2.9025950000000007],["2017/01/23",3.0344140000000004],["2017/01/24",3.156505],["2017/01/25",2.18585],["2017/02/04",0.200327],["2017/02/05",0.700937],["2017/02/06",0.8522410000000002],["2017/02/07",0.651459]]}];

  loadData(jsonData, '0', 'Column');

  // load json data
  function loadData(jsonData, id, chartType) {
    // create data table
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    switch (chartType) {
      case 'Column':
        // add date column
        dataTable.addColumn('date', 'Date');
        var aggColumns = [];
        var viewColumns = [0, {
          calc: function (dt, row) {
            return formatDate.formatValue(dt.getValue(row, 0));
          },
          label: dataTable.getColumnLabel(0),
          type: 'string'
        }];

        $.each(jsonData, function(productIndex, product) {
          // add product column
          var colIndex = dataTable.addColumn('number', product.name);
          viewColumns.push(colIndex);
          aggColumns.push({
            aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum,
            column: colIndex+1,
            label: dataTable.getColumnLabel(colIndex),
            type: dataTable.getColumnType(colIndex)
          });

          // add product data
          $.each(product.data, function(dataIndex, data) {
            var rowIndex = dataTable.addRow();
            var rowDate = new Date(data[0]);
            dataTable.setValue(rowIndex, 0, new Date(rowDate.getFullYear(), rowDate.getMonth(), 1));
            dataTable.setValue(rowIndex, colIndex, data[1]);
          });
        });

        var dataView = new google.visualization.DataView(dataTable);
        dataView.setColumns(viewColumns);
        var groupData = google.visualization.data.group(
          dataView,
          [0, 1],
          aggColumns
        );
        var dataView = new google.visualization.DataView(groupData);
        dataView.hideColumns([0]);
        dataTable = dataView;
        break;
    }

    // draw chart
    $(window).resize(function () {
      drawChart(id, chartType, dataTable);
    });
    drawChart(id, chartType, dataTable);
  }

  // draw chart
  function drawChart(id, chartType, dataTable) {
    if (!charts.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
      charts[id] = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        chartType: 'ColumnChart',
        containerId: 'chart-' + id,
        options: {
          isStacked: true
        }
      });
    }
    var dash = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard'));
    dash.bind([controlCat, controlStr], charts[id]);
    dash.draw(dataTable);
  }

});
```

```css
.control {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="dashboard">
<div class="control" id="string_div"></div>
  <div class="control" id="category_div"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart-0"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: when i use with more than one variable at that time i got error like "One or more participants failed to draw()×" so is there problem with draw method?

Comment: yes when i use with second variable data in same function example : var jsonData2 = " "  loadData(jsonData2, '1', 'Column');

Comment: guess i need to see the code, do you want to edit the question?

Comment: hi i got error when there is no data in a variable so how can i display blank charts?  i got error appear like this  "Not enough columns given to draw the requested chart."