# tricky part of google charts Column with drill down functionality?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

i am creating google charts and I already implement top 5 user column charts after that if you select first user column than displaying first user page history data from other variables(eachuser_data) its easy implement function in high charts! but in google charts, I don't know about add events.addListener work or not in this problem. let me know google charts provide click event on each column and display other graphs in same graph draw function. ?  thank you in advance

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var charts = {};
  var options = {
    Column: {
      chartArea: {
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        top: 24,
        left: 64,
        right: 32,
        bottom: 48,
      },
      'vAxis': {
        title: 'Cost in USD ($)', format:'$#',
      },
      height: '100%',
      legend: {
        position: 'bottom'
      },
      width: '100%'
    }
    };
  //  columns charts data
  //top 5 user data with total click 
  var jsonData = [["johan",69],["jack",23],["scott",24],["x",5],["y",10]];
  loadData(jsonData, '1', 'Column');
  //specifc user data 
   var user1 = [["report1",45],["report2",40],["index.html",50]];
   var user2 = [["report1",4],["report2",3],["index.html",5]];
   var user3 = [["report1",4],["report2",3],["index.html",5]];
   var user4 = [["report1",4],["report2",3],["index.html",5]];
   var user5 = [["report1",4],["report2",3],["index.html",5]];
 


  // load json data
  function loadData(jsonData, id, chartType) {
    // create data table
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

       // add date column
       dataTable.addColumn('string', 'Total numbe of click');
       var rowIndex = dataTable.addRow();
       dataTable.setValue(rowIndex, 0, dataTable.getColumnLabel(0));
       $.each(jsonData, function(productIndex, product) {
        var colIndex = dataTable.addColumn('number', product[0]);
          // add product data
          dataTable.setValue(rowIndex, colIndex, product[1]);
        });
         // draw chart
    $(window).resize(function () {
      drawChart(id, dataTable);
    });
    drawChart(id, dataTable);
  }


  function drawChart(id, dataTable) {
    if (!charts.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
      charts[id] = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        chartType: 'ColumnChart',
        containerId: 'chart-' + id,
        options:  {
          vAxis: {
            title: 'Cost in USD ($)',
            format: '$#',
          },
          width: '100%',
          height: '100%',
          legend: {
            position: 'bottom'
          },
        },
      });
    }
     charts[id].setDataTable(dataTable);
    charts[id].draw();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart-1"></div>
```

Comment: Does google charts make the charts with canvas, or with HTML elements? If it's just normal HTML elements, you can easily add an event listener to the tag for that row/column, but if it's done in canvas then you'll have to do some tricky stuff and track their mouse position to determine if it's within the bounds of that row/column.

Comment: its using canvas.. that's pro...

Answer (score 0):

to know which column has been clicked / selected,
listen for the `'select'` event

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', chartSelection);
```

then use chart method `getSelection()` to get the row and column index of the column selected
`getSelection` will return an array of objects

```
[{row: 0, column: 1}]
```

the select event will fire both when a column is selected and un-selected
be sure to check the length of the array return by `getSelection()`
before trying to access the array contents

for column charts, only one column can be selected at a time
so the values of the selection will always be the first element in the array

```
function chartSelection() {
  var selection = chart.getSelection();
  if (selection.length > 0) {
    var row = selection[0].row;
    var col = selection[0].column;
    var xValue = data.getValue(row, 0);
    var yValue = data.getValue(row, col);
    console.log('selection: ' + xValue + ' = ' + yValue);
  } else {
    console.log('nothing selected');
  }
}
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['x', 'y0', 'y1'],
    ['A', 6, 7],
    ['B', 7, 9],
    ['C', 8, 11],
    ['D', 9, 11],
    ['E', 5, 6]
  ]);

  var options = {
    legend: {
      alignment: 'end',
      position: 'top'
    }
  };

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(container);

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', chartSelection);

  function chartSelection() {
    var selection = chart.getSelection();
    if (selection.length > 0) {
      var row = selection[0].row;
      var col = selection[0].column;
      var xValue = data.getValue(row, 0);
      var yValue = data.getValue(row, col);
      console.log('selection: ' + xValue + ' = ' + yValue);
    } else {
      console.log('nothing selected');
    }
  }

  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: hi thnx for prompt response.. i just add images for charts i need something like if you click on the first column after that render new charts in the same area with different data from specific user data...  as example, if you select john column then draw new function with new chart which is stored in different variable  ..with spcific user history i alredy add in edituserdata variable  ...

Comment: like this functionality https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-drilldown

Comment: exmaple: https://jsfiddle.net/60q9bvko/10/  i tried with this example but its not work with my problem...  my code : https://jsfiddle.net/7jrhpLst/9/

Comment: i am just stuck with how to making dynamic  function selectHandler()

Comment: hi can you review this que. ?
 when you are free...thank you..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51086089/how-to-select-only-top-columns-in-stacked-columns-in-google-charts-using-selecth